# How to get peak memory usage for a azure virtual machine while running pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

I am running a pipeline that contains PowerShell script to execute an application. How I can monitor that memory usage of VM when the pipeline is running. I tried monitoring it manually by login to RDP but it is not showing any usage of memory as part of that pipeline.

Comment: You need to provide more details about the question. Are you using Azure DevOps Pipeline to run the powershell script? If yes, how you run the powershell script to execute application? Are you using Self-hosted agent(installed on Azure VM) to run the Pipeline?

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT, Yes I am using Azure DevOps Pipeline to run the PowerShell script and YML file is starting the PowerShell script that have code to run the application and providing the necessary input to application. Yes, I am using self hosted agent to run pipeline.

Comment: Please check the answer below and check if the built-in Pipeline debug log can meet your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this doc: [Review logs to diagnose pipeline issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting/review-logs?view=azure-devops)

> Azure pipeline logs can now capture resource utilization metrics such as memory, CPU usage and available disk space. The logs also include resources used by the pipeline agent and child processes including tasks run in a job. If you suspect your pipeline job may run into resource constraints, enable verbose logs to have resource utilization information injected into pipeline logs. This works on any agent, independent from hosting model.

To get the memory usage of the Pipeline agent, I suggest that you can directly use the built-in feature to enable the debug log to get the environment details in Azure DevOps Pipeline.

Here are the steps:

Step1: Enable the option: **Enable system diagnostics** when running YAML pipeline.

[image]

Step2: You can check the Pipeline log of each task. Then you will find the Memory usage during the pipeline task execution.

For example:

```
##[debug]Agent environment resources - Disk: D:\ Available 12480.00 MB out of 14333.00 MB, Memory: Used 1862.00 MB out of 7167.00 MB, CPU: Usage 34.28%
```

[image]

Comment: I have enabled this option in my pipeline run but, I am not getting these memory, disk and CPU related information in log.  Even if get these information then also it won't be useful. My requirement is to check what is the peak memory utilization of VM throughout this pipeline run.

Comment: @Abhi If you don't see the relevant information after enabling the option, you can check the agent version and update to the latest 3.234.0. It will display the real-time occupied memory information in each Task. You can compare it to get peak memory.